# How to move spriteKit node up and down with a button

Tags: ios, xcode, sprite-kit

I want to move my sprite up and down using a button. Since you cant use UIButtons in sprite Kit i am using different SpriteKitNodes. The nodes will be arrow images. But i want to use the arrow images to move my original sprite but simply touching it. I thought that I would use SKAction but I'm stuck. Is it possible to move one sprite using another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There may not be any provision for buttons in SpriteKit, but one can easily subclass SKSpriteNode to act as a button. I have created such a class which is available on GitHub [here](https://github.com/akashgupta88/AGSpriteButton).

Using `SKAction` for movement based on direction buttons is not advisable. Instead, you need to use flags for direction buttons upon which you will move the node in the `-update:` method.

Maintain the flags as instance variables.

```
@implementation MyScene
{
    BOOL upDirection;
    BOOL downDirection;
}
```

Initialise them to FALSE in the `-initWithSize:` method.

This is how you should handle the flags in the -update method:

```
-(void)update:(CFTimeInterval)currentTime
{
    /* Called before each frame is rendered */

    if (upDirection)
    {
        myNode.position = CGPointMake(myNode.position.x, myNode.position.y + 5); //Increment value can be adjusted
    }

    if (downDirection)
    {
        myNode.position = CGPointMake(myNode.position.x, myNode.position.y - 5); //Decrement value can be adjusted
    }
}
```